# Is there a way to disable the online/offline notification for one contact?

Tags: skype

I have one Skype contact which is going permanently online/offline. I don't want to block/delete the person but it is really unbelievable annoying to see ten times a hour the Skype notification:

[image]

Is there a way/hack to disable this notification for **one** contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more or less a very simple solution which may not be suitable for everybody because it has restrictions.

Right click on the contact and select "Remove from contacts". Then, the notifications stop but the person cannot contact you. In my case this is OK because this is a "one-way" contact, e.q. only I start a call/chat.

When I have to contact the person I select "Add to contacts" and the person is available again for me.

In the meantime there is a question mark in the contact icon:

[image]